# How can I select a search suggestion using selenium? The site prevents me from just clicking on submit, requires a selection

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to make searching for temporary apartments a bit easier on myself, but a website with listings for these apartments requires me to select a suggestion from their drop down list before I can click on submit. No matter how complete the entry in the search box might be.

The ultimate hope here is that I can get forward to the search results and then extract contact information from each listing. I was able to extract the data I need from a listing using Beautiful soup and Requests, but I had to paste in the URL for that specific listing into my code.  I didn't get that far. If anyone has a suggestion on how to perhaps circumvent the landing page to get to the relevant listings, please let me know.

I tried just splicing the town name and the state name into the address bar by looking at how it's written after a successful search but that didn't work.

The site is [Mein Monteurzimmer](https://mein-monteurzimmer.de/).

Here is my  code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


driver = webdriver.Firefox()


webpage = r"https://mein-monteurzimmer.de"
print('Prosim vnesi zeljeno mesto') #Please enter the town to search
searchterm = input()

driver.get(webpage)

sbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/cpagearea/section/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/section/form/div/input")
sbox.send_keys(searchterm)

ddown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/cpagearea/section/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/section/form/div")
ddown.select_by_value(1)

webdriver.wait(2)

#select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/cpagearea/section/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/section/form/div")

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/cpagearea/section/div[2]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/section/form/button")
submit.click
```

When I inspect the search box I can't find anything related to the suggestions until I enter a text. Then I can't click on the HTML code because that dismisses the suggestions. It's quite frustrating.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Inspecting suggestions]

So I'm blindly trying to select something.

The error here is:

AttributeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'

I tried something with select, but that doesn't work with the way I tried this.

I am stumped and the solutions I could find were specific for other sites like Google or Amazon and I couldn't make sense if it.

Does anyone know how I could make this work?

Here's the code for getting information out of a listing, which I'll have to expand on to get the other data:

```
import bs4, requests

def getMonteurAddress(MonteurUrl):
    res = requests.get(MonteurUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('section.c:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > dl:nth-child(1) > dd:nth-child(2)')
    return elems[0].text.strip()




address = getMonteurAddress('https://mein-monteurzimmer.de/105742/monteurzimmer/deggendorf-monteurzimmer-deggendorf-pensionfelix%40googlemailcom')
print('Naslov je ' + address) #print call to see if it gets the right data
```

Comment: What is the `searchterm`?

Comment: The `searchterm` is defined by input(). Just thought it'd be neat to enter what I'm looking for into a prompt. This site accepts german cities, towns and postal codes for the search. 

But no matter how complete your info is, you can't just go ENTER to continue. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: Although in this specific case, I was looking at Deggendorf, Bayern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see once you type in, there is a list of divs creating. Now you need to get the a valid locator for these divs. To get the locator for these created divs you need to inspect elements in debug pause mode ( F12--> Source Tab --> F8).

Try below code to select first matching address as you typed.

```
sbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Adresse, PLZ oder Ort eingeben']")
sbox.send_keys(searchterm)
addessXpath = "//div[contains(text(),'"+searchterm+"')]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(addessXpath).click()
```

Note : If there are more than one matching address , first one will be selected.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I didn't know I could pause the source, that's huge! :)