# How to click on search text results in selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

How to click on a specific text of search text box results in selenium WebDriver. In my case search text box is "School".

I'm sending keys "RGSchool1" in the text box "School" and then I want to click on "RGScool" when it shows up as results under the text box.

I tried all below approached by it's throwing "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException"

1. Enter text and tab out
2. Enter text and send enter key
3. Absolute path  -  /html[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvqO.png)/body[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvqO.png)/div[7]/ul[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvqO.png)/li[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvqO.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvqO.png)/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIvqO.png)
4. Relative path  -  //span[@class='select2-match']

HTML body:

```
<div class="select2-result-label" style="" xpath="1">
<span class="select2-match">RGSchoo</span>
l1 [rgschool1]</div>
```

Code:
//Finding elements

```
@FindBy(id = "s2id_User_OrgId")
public WebElement clickJurisdiction;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[6]/div[1]/input[1]")
public WebElement keyInJurisdiction;

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='s2id_User_OrgUnitId']//a[@class='select2-        choice']")
public WebElement clickSchool;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[7]/div[1]/input[1]")
public WebElement keyInSchool;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[7]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[1]")
public WebElement schoolSearchResult2;
```

Call method:

```
public void enterNewUserData() {

    SeleniumTestHelper.enterText(firstName, Config.getProperty("FirstName"));
    SeleniumTestHelper.enterText(middleName, Config.getProperty("MiddleName"));
    SeleniumTestHelper.enterText(lastName, Config.getProperty("LastName"));
    SeleniumTestHelper.enterText(preferredName, Config.getProperty("PreferredName"));
    
    SeleniumTestHelper.clickOnButton(clickJurisdiction);
    SeleniumTestHelper.enterText(keyInJurisdiction, Config.getProperty("Jurisdiction"));
    SeleniumTestHelper.enter(keyInJurisdiction);

    SeleniumTestHelper.clickOnButton(clickSchool);
    SeleniumTestHelper.enterText(keyInSchool, Config.getProperty("School"));
    SeleniumTestHelper.clickOnButton(schoolSearchResult2); // It fails here
```

Please help me to find a solution. I'm new to this kind of scenario.

Please see the below-attached screenshot.

Screenshot before entering data:

[image: Screenshot before entering data]

[Screenshot after entering data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfpwL.png)

Comment: Can you post your full code ,then it will be more easier to answer

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed - Thanks for your time. Just modified my question with code details.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Thank you so much for your time in sharing that post. Yes, I'm a newbie here and figuring out how to add complete stack trace as StackOverflow is not allowing me to do so.  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Here i have answered a similar question. This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467976/how-can-i-select-a-search-suggestion-using-selenium-the-site-prevents-me-from-j/63469553#63469553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the element with text as **RGSchool1** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  @FindBy(cssSelector = "ul.select2-results div.select2-result-label > span.select2-match")
  public WebElement schoolSearchResult2;
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//ul[@class='select2-results']//div[@class='select2-result-label']/span[@class='select2-match']")
  public WebElement schoolSearchResult2;
  ```

Comment: DebanjanB- Thanks a lot and appreciate your time. CSS selector which you provided worked with a wait of 2 seconds before clicking the element. :)

Comment: @user13996330 _...worked with a wait..._ I saw it coming, as you are using _Page Objects_. I don't suggest `sleeps` so _WebDriverWait_ was inevitable. But then the solution becomes way too complicated.